How to formulate conditional multiplications in Goggle sheets to calculate discounts based on volume
I have a business that makes discounts depending on the number of days that we work for a client. Less days, less discount.
I need a formula that takes the base price of our service and multiplies it by a given discount that is determined by the number of days the job will last for.
So I want something on the lines of "if days = 1-4, multiply by 1 (0% discount), if days = 4-9, multiply by 0.9 (90% discount)", etc.
I have a column for the number of days, a column with the base price, and a table with the discount percentages in my sheet, so I can just reference those cells.
Any help would be WILDLY appreciated.
cheers!
Honestly, haven't tried much cause I dont even know where to begin.

It would help if you could share a sample sheet with realistic-demo data and expected output(manually entered) so as for us to get a clear picture & workout a solution. You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker provided by docs community forum incase you do not wish to share a sheet from your google account.

You can use a formula like the following:
=if(A2<=4,0,if(and(A2<=9,A2>4),0.9,if(A2>9,0.95,"define in function")))

Essentially, it's a nested if statement. If number of days is <= 4, then multiply by the designated discount amount. If not, move onto the next logic - If number of days is <= 9 and >4, then multiply by the discount.
You can also create a legend to refer to and use vlookup to multiply by the discount like the information on the right table of the following doc:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vFO1vHi9RJNKDUZLpkYSVxthpUlfXwpprUhqfGobF8s/edit?usp=sharing
